# Handling of MethodArgumentNotValidException overridden by DefaultErrorAttributes

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-web

My goal is to have a custom response body for validation errors. This is a very common case and I've read lots of posts/blogs/articles and I've even implemented this myself in the past. For some reason, I cannot figure this out.

I have this `@RestControllerAdvice`

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ErrorHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  private final MessageSource messageSource;

  @Override
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
      HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    ValidationErrorDTO validationError = ValidationErrorDTO.builder()
        .fieldErrors(ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().stream()
            .map(fieldError -> FieldErrorDTO.builder()
                .field(fieldError.getField())
                .message(messageSource.getMessage(fieldError, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()))
                .build())
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .build();
    LOGGER.debug("W3MnsZ validation error: {}", validationError);
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(validationError, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
  }
}
```

====

```
@ToString
@Builder
public class ValidationErrorDTO {

  private final List<FieldErrorDTO> fieldErrors;
}
```

====

```
@ToString
@Builder
@Getter
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class FieldErrorDTO {

  private final String field;
  private final String message;
}
```

My `ErrorHandler.handleMethodArgumentNotValid()` gets hit, but the actual response body returned to the client is not from my `ValidationErrorDTO`.

```
{
  "timestamp": 1523115887261,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException",
  "errors": [
    {
      "codes": [
        "NotEmpty.myDTO.field.another.lastly",
        "NotEmpty.field.another.lastly",
        "NotEmpty.lastly",
        "NotEmpty.java.lang.String",
        "NotEmpty"
      ],
      "arguments": [
        {
          "codes": [
            "myDTO.field.another.lastly",
            "field.another.lastly"
          ],
          "arguments": null,
          "defaultMessage": "field.another.lastly",
          "code": "field.another.lastly"
        }
      ],
      "defaultMessage": "may not be empty",
      "objectName": "myDTO",
      "field": "field.another.lastly",
      "rejectedValue": null,
      "bindingFailure": false,
      "code": "NotEmpty"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Validation failed for object='myDTO'. Error count: 1",
  "path": "/myPath"
}
```

I've figured out that what's happening is `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DefaultErrorAttributes` is getting hit and somehow overriding my custom response body.

What do I do to allow my custom response body to be returned to the client?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out.

`ValidationErrorDTO.fieldErrors` had no getter.

```
@ToString
@Builder
@Getter
public class ValidationErrorDTO {

  @Singular
  private final List<FieldErrorDTO> fieldErrors;
}
```

Now it works and we get response:

```
{
  "fieldErrors": [
    {
      "field": "field.another.lastly",
      "message": "may not be empty"
    }
  ]
}
```